# Graphql Invalid CSRF Token

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, csrf

I want to implement the graphql in express server but because of using csurf in server graphql give this error: ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token.
and i dont know how to use csrf protection in side graphql system. 
if anyone know please let me know

ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token
    at csrf (G:\Project\API\UserManagement\node_modules\csurf\index.js:112:19)

```
import express      from 'express';
import mongoose     from 'mongoose';
import bodyParser   from 'body-parser';
import passport     from 'passport';
import path         from 'path';
import session      from 'express-session';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser'
import cors         from 'cors';
import csrf         from 'csurf';
import xssFilter    from 'x-xss-protection';
import hpp          from 'hpp';
import helmet       from 'helmet';
import userRouter from '../routes/userRouter';
import rootRouter from '../routes/rootRouter';

import expressGraphql from 'express-graphql';
import schema         from '../schema';

require('../services/passport');

/////////////////START DATABASE CONFIG///////////////////////////
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_ADDRESS,{ useNewUrlParser: true });
mongoose.connection.on('connected'   ,()=>{console.log("connection established successfully")});
mongoose.connection.on('error'       ,(err)=>{console.log('connection to mongo failed ' + err)});
mongoose.connection.on('disconnected',()=>{console.log('mongo db connection closed')})
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

/////////////////END DATABASE CONFIG///////////////////////////
const app = express();
app.use(helmet())
app.use(helmet.noSniff())
app.use(helmet.ieNoOpen())
/////////////////START APP MIDDLEWARE///////////////////////////
require('dotenv').config({
    path:path.resolve(process.cwd(),'config/keys/.env')
})
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
app.use(hpp())
app.disable('x-powered-by')

const whiteList = [process.env.CORS_APPROVED_ADDRESS,`http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}`];
const corsOptionsDelegate = {
    origin:(origin,cb)=>{
        ( whiteList.indexOf(origin) !== -1 || !origin)?
            cb(null,true)
           :cb(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'));
    }
}
app.use(cors(corsOptionsDelegate))

///////////////END APP MIDDLEWARE///////////////////////////
let RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);

app.use(session({
    secret:"3f9faa8bc0e722172cc0bdafede9f3f217474e47",
    resave:false,
    saveUninitialized:false,
    store:new RedisStore({
        prefix:"session:auth:"
    }),
    cookie:{
        maxAge:30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        httpOnly:true,
    }
}))
app.use(csrf())
app.use(xssFilter())
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
////////////////START GRAPHQL CONFIG///////////////////////////
app.use('/graphql',expressGraphql({
    schema,
    graphiql:true
}))
////////////////START ROUTER CONFIG///////////////////////////
app.use('/',userRouter)
app.use('/',rootRouter)
/////////////////END ROUTER CONFIG///////////////////////////

export default app;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cookie:{
    maxAge:30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    httpOnly:true,
    sameSite: "lax", //csrf security

}
```

`sameSite:"lax"` will handle the csrf security. For more:

https://portswigger.net/web-security/csrf/samesite-cookies

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't really need to worry about using CSRF protection when using graphql or rest endpoint. The requests to the service should be stateless and not really rely on cookies or session data.

I would recommend reading this (it should apply to graphql also as it is an api):
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/166724/should-i-use-csrf-protection-on-rest-api-endpoints